# React Native search bar dispatch API call

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have multiple tabs where in three of those there is a FlatList component where I need to be able to search for items. Now in my Header I want to make a SearchBar and be able to make an API call to get what the user searched for and to display the result(s) in the FlatList. I am using react-navigation/native ^5.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render a custom component in the `options` props. [More details here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component)

```
function SearchBar() {
      const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Useless Placeholder');
      return (
       <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
        value={value}
       />
      );
    }

function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: props => <SearchBar {...props} /> }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: @stefan0905 If this answers your question. Please accept it as an answer so that it will be helpful for others!